# Mnesia: DAT file huge, remove old records to resize it

Tags: resize, erlang, mnesia

I'm trying to reduce the DAT file size about a Mnesia table (disc_copies), but I don't find yet the solution. I can't truncate the file or create a new one, I must work in this table during the system is working.

The procedure that I considered was to delete the oldest records, but this isn't enough because the DAT file size remain the same until I restart the node.

So there is a way to force the sync to disk without restart the entire node?

Comment: Try set smaller auto_save parameters for storage properties on creating table

Comment: You could probably trim your data and then spin up another node, sync/replicate to it, and let it take over, discarding the previous node. Of course your total storage size will get a lot worse before it gets better!

Comment: For the purpose of forcing the sync, you could use dets:sync/1 http://erlang.org/doc/man/dets.html#sync-1

You probably need a combination of reviewing your data format (consider types and fields) and maybe some cleanup process to keep going.